# Registering third party DLL into GAC (.Net Framework 4.6.1)

Tags: c#, .net, dll, gac

I am trying to get a third party DLL to be registered in GAC by using GACUtil.

It says succesfully added to the assembly cache. However, when I try to instance it . it throws exception saying it's not installed . I am using the code below to test the DLL

```
  try
            {
                var factory = DbProviderFactories.GetFactory("NexusDB.ADOProvider");
                var conn = factory.CreateConnection();
                Console.WriteLine("COnnection created");
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
            }

            Console.ReadKey();
```

How do I properly register the DLL?

Comment: Sounds like that third party vendor has its own documentation, https://www.nexusdb.com/support/index.php?q=adoprovider_runtimeinstaller And the steps are differently from what you did.

Comment: Reading the docs on [DbProviderFactory](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd0w4a2z(v=vs.110).aspx) indicates registration is a bit more involved than just adding the assembly to the GAC. The machine.config file must also be modified. Have you done that?